# Custom Fields in component Articles - Joomla 3.6.4

Tags: custom-field

i need add 2 fields to the component content (articles), need add 2 images and try some examples but don't work :-( have a github with the last try

https://github.com/javimata/plg_addfield

Can help me to check what happend? what i do wrong?

Comment: Is there an error message? What's not working?

Answer (score 2):

Custom field will be supported natively in the upcoming Joomla 3.7. 
But if you're in hurry, you can try [Aixeena Plugin](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/aixeena-cck)

Answer (score 2):

I have used **Fields Attach** on a few projects and it worked well.

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/fieldsattach

http://fieldsattach.com

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try digital peaks' dpfields. This is the extension where the 3.7 custom fields are based on. It will probably be possible to migrate from dpfields to j3.7! core custom fields.
https://joomla.digital-peak.com/products/dpfields

Answer (score 2):

Try Joomla 3.7.*, custom fields option is included in it.

Read article for help
https://www.joomshaper.com/blog/how-to-use-joomla-3-7-custom-fields